# setTimeout not firing jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout

I am trying to call a function with setTimeout inside of a **document.ready()** and a **jquery.mouseleave()**. For some reason nothing happens, it doens't even give me an error.
Code(JS):

```
var stay = false;
function dropHide()
{
    alert(stay);
    if(stay == false)
    {
        $("#products-dropdown").slideUp();
    }
}
$(document).ready(function()
{
    $("#products-item").mouseenter(function()
    {
        stay = true;
        $("#products-dropdown").slideDown();
    });
    $("#products-dropdown-item-1").mouseenter(function()
    {
        stay = true;
    });
    $("#products-dropdown-item-2").mouseenter(function()
    {
        stay = true;
    });
    $("#products-dropdown-item-1").mouseleave(function()
    {
        stay = false;
        setTimeout("dropHide", 400);
    });
    $("#products-dropdown-item-2").mouseleave(function()
    {
        stay = false;
        setTimeout("dropHide", 400);
    });
    $("#products-item").mouseleave(function()
    {
        stay = false;
        setTimeout("dropHide", 400);
    });
});
```

Comment: Remove quotes from function name. Try this: `setTimeout(dropHide, 400);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTimeout` expects first argument to be function expression, in provided example, `"dropHide"` is being passed which is of `string` datatype.

Try this:

```
setTimeout(dropHide, 400);
```

Comment: __convert__ ? I suppose `setTimeout` expects firts argument to be function expression, OP is passing `string`

Comment: Well, it looks like i'm really used to jQuery

Comment: @RayonDabre I'm not very good in English to make me explain well what I want to say .. so you can edit my answer with the right meanings

Comment: I use jQuery more, and jquery uses that kind of syntax.

Comment: @Jojo01 you can make a test here by removing the '' https://jsfiddle.net/mohamedyousef1980/s87ffghe/

Answer (score 0):

use like this...

```
setTimeout("dropHide();", 400);
```